# Salesforce APEX Test Class for Simple Trigger

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex, apex-code

I've been going nuts over this.  Nothing in my IF loop is firing through my test class and I cannot figure out why.  I have done a lot of reading online and it appears that I am doing things correctly but it still hasn't solved my code coverage.  This is the last line that runs: 
If (isWithin == True){
after that I can't get anything to run within that IF loop, I have reversed the logic and it still doesn't run.  I feel like I will kick myself when someone points it out but here is my code:

```
trigger caseCreatedDurringBusinessHours on Case (after insert) {

//Create list and map for cases
List<case> casesToUpdate = new List<case>();
Map<Id, case> caseMap = new Map<Id, case>();

// Get the default business hours
BusinessHours bh = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault=true];

// Create Datetime on for now in the local timezone.
    Datetime targetTime =System.now();

// Find whether the time now is within the default business hours
Boolean isWithin;
    if ( Test.isRunningTest() ){
        Boolean isWithin = True;
    }
    else{
        Boolean isWithin = BusinessHours.isWithin(bh.id, targetTime); 
    }

// Update cases being inserted if during business hours
If (isWithin == True){

    // Add cases to map if not null
    For(case newcase : trigger.new) {
        if(newcase.id != null){
            caseMap.put(newcase.Id, newcase);
        }
    }

    // Check that cases are in the map before SOQL query and update
    If(caseMap.size() > 0){

        // Query cases
        casesToUpdate = [SELECT Id, Created_During_Business_Hours__c FROM case WHERE Id IN: caseMap.keySet()];

        // Assign new value for checkbox field
        for (case c: casesToUpdate){
                c.Created_During_Business_Hours__c = TRUE;
        }

        // if the list of cases isnt empty, update them
        if (casesToUpdate.size() > 0)
        {
            update casesToUpdate;
        }

    }


}
```

}

and here is my test class:

```
@isTest
private class BusinessHoursTest {

@isTest static void createCaseNotInBusinessHours() {
    case c = new case();
    c.subject = 'Test Subject';
    insert c;

}

}
```

Comment: For clarification, I have 43% code coverage with my test class and need that above 75%

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just copy the main logic to the apex class and just call the method of apex class from the apex trigger.

So it will make it more easy to write the test class.

Let me know if you need more help in this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've figured this out by now but this block of code is re-defining the `isWithin` variable inside of the if/else blocks:

```
Boolean isWithin;

if (Test.isRunningTest()) {
    Boolean isWithin = True;
} else {
    Boolean isWithin = BusinessHours.isWithin(bh.id, targetTime); 
}
```

That needs to be:

```
Boolean isWithin;

if (Test.isRunningTest()) {
    isWithin = True;
} else {
    isWithin = BusinessHours.isWithin(bh.id, targetTime); 
}
```

Or rather a ternary operator for the cleanest code:

```
Boolean isWithin = !Test.isRunningTest() ? BusinessHours.isWithin(bh.id, targetTime) : true;
```